# OAuth test server / application

Tags: oauth

I am thinking about creating an OAuth library in LabVIEW, but for testing this during development I would like to use some test server, without overloading an existing service that has **real** users.

Is there such a server or is there an easy server application (Linux or Windows) that I can run myself?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

http://term.ie/oauth/example/index.php is a live example of the php code found in http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/example/.

The endpoints are:
http://term.ie/oauth/example/request_token.php
http://term.ie/oauth/example/access_token.php
http://term.ie/oauth/example/echo_api.php

The consumer key and secret are:

- Consumer Key: key
- Consumer Secret: secret

The tokens returned are:

- Request token: requestkey
- Request secret: requestsecret

and

- Access token: accesskey
- Access secret: accesssecret

I tested it with it's own client code at http://term.ie/oauth/example/client.php and it worked with HMAC and PLAINTEXT signature methods.

RSA signature would require the public and private keys used in the test server found here:

http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/OAuth_TestServer.php

For a quick and dirty test this'll probably work, if you're worried about using someone elses server, it should be fairly easy to deploy the code from http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/ locally or on a server you have access to that is running php.

Answer (score 8):

you can try OAuth.io and their open source daemon oauthd on Github : https://github.com/oauth-io/oauthd

Answer (score 1):

You can try ApiFest OAuth 2.0 Server (https://github.com/apifest/apifest-oauth20). Follow the steps described to start the server. Enjoy!