# Is there an authorization server that I can use to test a client implementation of OAuth 2.0?

Tags: testing, oauth-2.0

> Related: [Is there an OAuth test server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524869/is-there-an-oauth-test-server)

Is there a service or website that I can use to test a client implementation of the OAuth 2.0 protocol? The question linked above points to some excellent resources but they currently implement v1.0 of OAuth.

Comment: Last time I had to debug my client OAuth 2.0 codeI just tried it against Facebook and Foursquare. Good question +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run your very own [Django OAuth 2.0 Server](http://hiidef.github.com/oauth2app/) or [Rack OAuth 2.0](https://github.com/flowtown/rack-oauth2-server)

There is also Apache's [Amber Authorization Server](https://cwiki.apache.org/AMBER/oauth-20-authorization-server.html)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that running an OAuth 2.0 server was as easy as setting up a Django app.