Using OAuth 2.0 Playground for Testing Authorization Code Flow in a Web Server Application
I am developing a web server application and would like to implement the Authorisation Code Flow using openid-client.
Can I use the OAuth 2.0 Playground (https://www.oauth.com/playground/) to simulate the Authorisation Code Flow in my application and test the redirection and stuff like that?

Looking at the playground's network communication I think it is not really using an OAuth2 service, so the answer is no. It only demonstrates what would happen but doesn't do it. You need an OAuth2 service instance useable for testing purposes. Check answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651543/is-there-an-authorization-server-that-i-can-use-to-test-a-client-implementation

@cly Thanks! the answers from your link are from 2011. Which OAuth 2.0 Servers for testing would you recommend in 2024?

This is a simulation to walk you through the process to help you learn the steps.
I would suggest a better option would be to utilize one of the provider's free trials or free tiers.
The site you linked is sponsored by Okta/Auth0, and they have a free option. I would stick to the Auth0 side unless you have a specific reason to use the Okta side, much more dev-friendly.
And, there are others that are dev-focused (although, I haven't validated how easy or featured they are) like WorkOS, Frontegg, Clerk, and plenty more.
I'd probably also avoid Microsoft/Azure/Entra and AWS IAM/Cognito as they're a little obtuse or specific in their feature-set. Keycloak is a nice open source project, but it can be a bit finnicky.
You could even do a sign-in with Google since that uses OIDC with the authorization code flow. But, you don't get control of the IdP side if you need to customize and test further things out.
